# jQuery notification with actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications

I am using a jQuery plugin for showing notifications.

so i can use something like this

```
show_notification("Successfully Saved your data","success");
```

we can use `html` content as `message`.

Now i want to perform some actions

ex.

```
show_notification("Do you want to save your data","success");
```

so this is a question to the user and user need to reply by clicking `yes` or `no` [both will be passed as html message]

what i need to do is when  user clicks on yes/no i need to perform some actions.

i can use `id`  or `class` to attach a click event,but i have many types of actions,and need to use very different `id` or `class`.

can i use a call back function or something like that ?

Please help me or give me your valuable suggestions .

Thank you.

**Note : I know that it is not possible with current plugin and not talking about its functionalities ,i am just trying to modify the plugin.**

Comment: Which jQuery plugin are you using?

Comment: @Chris Francis thanks..and its irrelevant to the question,take the note.

Comment: No, it is entirely critical to the question. Whether or not you can pass a callback function to `show_notification` depends entirely on whether or not `show_notification` has been explicitly designed to accept a callback function.

Comment: It's not irrelevant, you haven't provided enough information. And it wasn't me that downvoted you, I'm simply asking you to clarify your question.

Comment: With regards to your update: if you're trying to modify the plugin, it is still relevant to know what it is you're trying to modify.

Comment: pardon me .. i am not trying to get the zip file containing the altered code of that plugin,what the plugin doing is just creating a div,prepending to the body,there is nothing more.

Comment: @ChrisFrancis i am sorry :) i am sure that it is very easy to get 100ds of downvotes if u dnt knw how to express things..

Comment: What does the `"success"` parameter do? There may be a "`confirm`" option you haven't found yet? On the most basic level, a [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm) dialog does what you want. I take it you want a styled version of that?

Comment: I think [this](http://demos.9lessons.info/jnotification/index.php) might be the plugin, in which case the second parameter is only for styling; there are other parameters as well, but they do not seem relevant either.

Comment: @ChrisFrancis: I've given you an answer, but as you'll see, it contains a whole lot of speculation, and some pseudo-code that I'll only have to guess at. I could've written a lot shorter post, and critically, I could have written things that were a lot more direct and helpful to you, if you wouldn't have persistently resisted to tell us about which plugin you were using. Next time people ask you for more information, try not to fight back - they're asking because they're trying to help you.

Comment: @DavidHedlund hehehe..there is no problm with giving details of that plugin :) that was just an example,nd u guys sticking on it.i always hv  types of actions negative nd positive,so i can set a option for that..thanks for ur answer .. i will check it and reply asap..thank u very much and really sorry for the troubles :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case there is no way to send a callback to your plugin, you would have to manually add the Yes/No-buttons to your message, and target them either by live delegates or by assigning a listener after the notification has been shown.

```
$(function() {

    $('body').on('click', '.notification-yes', function() {
       // yes-callback
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.notification-no', function() {
       // no-callback
    });

});

show_notification('Do you want to proceed? <button class="notification-yes">Yes</button> <button class="notification-no">No</button>', 'success');
```

If it is [this plugin](http://demos.9lessons.info/jnotification/index.php) that you're using, you'll want your listeners to call `closeNotification()`. I realize that the syntax is not exactly the same, but that could be a versioning issue. It'd be easier to help you with the specifics if we knew the details of the plugin you're using.

You'll also need a way of knowing which notification was showing when the button was clicked. You could of course have unique button class names for different notifications. Another approach, if there is always just one notification showing at any given time, would be to have a small state object for the callback of interest. For instance:

```
var myNotifications = {
    onYes: function() { },
    onNo: function() { }
};

$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.notification-yes', function() {
       myNotifications.onYes();
       closeNotification();
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.notification-no', function() {
       myNotifications.onNo();
       closeNotification();
    });
});

function showCertainNotification() {
    myNotifications.onYes = function() {
        // specific callback for this notification.
    };

    show_notification('Confirm? <button class="notification-yes">Yes</button> <button class="notification-no">No</button>', 'success');
}
```

If there could be several notifications showing at any one time, a simple variable like that won't do. In that case you'd have to wrap your message in a container, the ID of which you could extract from your listener, and call a specific callback based on that, or passing that as a parameter. I won't go into detail here, seeing as the simple nature of `show_notification` implies an equally simple manner of `close_notification`. Since no ID's seems to be anywhere to be found, I'll assume that multiple active notifications are not supported.

A more appealing solution might have been to modify the plugin itself, rather than to work around it, so that you could pass callback functions directly to the plugin. Something like this:

```
show_notification({
    message: 'Confirm',
    type: 'success',
    buttons: [
        { caption: 'Yes', click: function() { } },
        { caption: 'No',  click: function() { } }
    ]
});
```

But of course, this is no way near possible to help you with, without first having a chance to look at what the plugin you're currently using looks like.

Comment: http://demos.9lessons.info/jnotification/index.php this the plugin ...let me try ..